# Representing Angular Scopes and Controllers on Sequence Diagrams

Tags: angularjs, uml, sequence-diagram

Does anyone have a recommended approach for creating sequence diagrams that include Angular scopes (or, though I don't need it in my own use case, both Angular scopes and directives)?

It may sound like an odd question, but I'm wondering if it is appropriate to use an approach like this:

User -> View -> $scope -> Controller -> Service

Since the $scope's operations were placed onto it by the controller, it leads to some redundant entries since almost everything that's called on the scope will be delegated through to the controller.  I'd be tempted to leave the $scope out of the diagram altogether, but I want to show how certain state that the $scope is managing is being updated.

I hope this makes sense; just looking for patterns and practices that would help visualize control flow better in Angular-centric applications.

Comment: For patterns and practices to visualize control flow in Angular applications, you might want to refer to my paper "Technical design in UML for AngularJS applications" (see www.admiraalit.nl).

Answer (score 2):

The scope is just the "glue" between the view and the controller, the medium between the two of them. So, in my opinion, it shouldn't be represented in a diagram. I think you should describe how the view communicates with the controller in terms of the controller methods as if there wasn't nothing between them.